# WCF service discovery with dynamic port 0 and TCP binding

Tags: .net, wcf, tcp, wcf-binding, ws-discovery

I would like to start a service (with Mex enabled with mex TCP Binding) on port 0 - say for contract "IHelloWorldOne" on a end point using net TCP binding again.

From my service's App.config

```
  <service name="Service.One.HelloWorldOne">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" name="Mex" kind="mexEndpoint" listenUriMode="Unique" />
    <endpoint name="Discovery" kind="udpDiscoveryEndpoint" />
    <endpoint address="1/tcp" binding="netTcpBinding" name="Service.One" contract="Service.One.IHelloWorldOne" listenUriMode="Unique" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:0/service" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

Note that, port is 0 - this basically lets windows give me an open port for the end point and this would mean that "mex" endpoint could get a random port.

On my client:

```
        FindCriteria findCriteria = FindCriteria.CreateMetadataExchangeEndpointCriteria(typeof(IHelloWorldOne));
        //FindCriteria findCriteria = new FindCriteria(typeof(IHelloWorldOne));
        findCriteria.MaxResults = 1;
        findCriteria.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
        findCriteria.Scopes.Add(new Uri(string.Format("net.tcp://sharedservice/{0}/", "SHAREDCONTEXT")));

        FindResponse response = discoveryClient.Find(findCriteria);
        try
        {
            if (response.Endpoints.Count > 0)
            {
                var mexClient = new MetadataExchangeClient(MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding());
                var contracts = new List<ContractDescription>() { ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(IHelloWorldOne)) };
                EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress(response.Endpoints[0].ListenUris[0]);
                var endpoints = MetadataResolver.Resolve(contracts, address, mexClient);
```

Note: I am using the ListenURI to get the metadata exchanged. However, when I try that - I run into this exception

Exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:50294/service/mex'. --->
System.InvalidOperationException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><Fault xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><Code><Value>Sender</Value><Subcode><Value xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">a:DestinationUnreachable</Value></Subcode></Code><Reason><Text xml:lang="en-US">
The message with To 'net.tcp://localhost:50294/service/mex' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  
Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.</Text></Reason></Fault>
```

I am able to see the port for mex endpoint on the listenURI but unable to connect to it.

The other approach I tried was to leave the mex end point as a constant and discover the service port - I was not able to get this done as well as the port is not available on the listenURI of the endpoint from the response.

So my question is, is there a way to bind to port 0 in WCF for Mex and service end points and also discover them? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

From your exception message:

> AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

This is because endpoint address should be exactly the same as you specified when creating endpoint (e.g. port = 0)

The problem is that MetadataResolver not using following overload of
MetadataExchangeClient class

```
public MetadataSet GetMetadata(
    EndpointAddress address,
    Uri via
)
```

Here **address** should be in your case **response.Address** (with port 0)

The **via** parameter should be actual Uri of your endpoint it listens on (e.g. have actual port number) in your case **response.Endpoints[0].ListenUris[0]**.

It appears that there is no simple way to use MetadataResolver with dynamic port.

In my case I have service on dynamic port and using discovery to find what port was assigned to the service.

On the client side I'm using following code:

```
FindResponse response = discoveryClient.Find(findCriteria);
var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
return ChannelFactory<IMyService>.CreateChannel(binding, response.Endpoints[0].Address, response.Endpoints[0].ListenUris[0]);
```

Here I'm specifying both endpoint address with port 0 and actual address with dynamically assigned port from ListenUris.

Hope this will help to solve your problem.